# How to configure properties and deploy application from Jenkins to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, deployment, automation

Is it possible to deploy a war file from Jenkins to tomcat with an application properties configuration?

Instead of building the war file from any version controll, I want to give a war file directly to Jenkins for deployment. Before that, some application properites(e.g., db connection, third-party services URL) will need to be configured according to the original deployed app and then deployed to tomcat. This might need to be done by writing some script?

For example, the deployed app is version 1.0 and db connection properties is port 5433. The war file which I gave is version 1.1 and the db port default is 5432. So, I have to update the properties in the war to 5433 for db port and deploy to tomcat to get a version 1.1 app and with correct db connectino settings(5433)

Does there have any plugin of Jenkins can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can do this through the scripts.
In the **Build** section of the Jenkins there is an option called **Execute Shell** - there you can do these things

1) Execute the script - which updates properties

```
sh script_with_changes.sh
```

2) Copy the war file as shown below using **rsync** command

```
rsync -avz /path/where/war/exists/xxx.war username@machineip:/tomcat/path/to/copy/xxx.war
```

Comment: Hi Ravindra, thanks for your reply. I am currently running Jenkins and deployment on Windows platform. So, I have to using windows batch command for change the properties? And actually, I would like to update the properties in the war file which the original app deployed in tomcat.

Comment: For example, the deployed app is version 1.0 and db connection properties is port 5433. The war file which I gave is version 1.1 and the db port default is 5432. So, I have to update the properties in the war to 5433 for db port and deploy to tomcat to get a version 1.1 app and with correct db connectino settings(5433)